# missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' while using classmethod in staticmethod

Tags: python-3.x

I write class `Person` in Python 3.8. When I use `calc_all()` method to calculate income for every instance in `instances`, I get an error.
Code:

```
import math
class Person:
    instances = []
    @classmethod
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.level = 1
        self.job = ""
        self.work_place = None
        Person.instances.append(self)
    def do_level(self,income):
        return income*math.sqrt(self.level*self.work_place.level)
    def calc_income(self):
        pass
    def calc_life_cost(self):
        pass
    def calc(self):
        income = self.calc_income()
        cost = self.calc_life_cost()
        return self.do_level(income) - cost
    @staticmethod
    def calc_all():
        zigma = 0
        for instance in Person.instances:
            zigma = zigma + instance.calc()
        return zigma

p = Person('X',12)
p2 = Person('Y',15)
print(Person.calc_all())
```

Error:

> ```
> zigma = zigma + instance.calc()
> TypeError: calc() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
> ```

Comment: What does the line `Person.instances.append(self)` make sense. Is it appending correctly???

Comment: Do u want to append name,age,etc to to the instances list????

Comment: @Arpit I'm not sure about my code, But when i print it : ```[<__main__.Person object at 0x000001F4C094E488>, <__main__.Person object at 0x000001F4C094E4C8>]``` I want a list of all person objects

Comment: What u basically want in in your instances list???

Comment: @Arpit every person object I create

Comment: You can't append object name. Object name is used to call the class functions outside the class. You can append the values u provided as argument to the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish by making `__init__` a classmethod? You could freely remove it. After this you will still have an error, since `self.work_place` does not have attribute level.

Comment: I reproduced your code and get an implementation error, you should add implementations for `calc_income` and `calc_life_cost`, cheers. And remove `@classmethod` from `__init__` you do not need it.

Comment: The problem was @classmethod, Thanks